# connect local environment to CloudSQL with private IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

I have hosted my application in a CloudRun Container and connected it to CloudSQL.
Everything is in a VPC Network and is running smoothly. Now I would like to modify data in production from a Database tool like DataGrid. Therefore I need to connect my local environment to my VPC-Network. I did this through a Cloud VPN Tunnel. Now I would like to connect to the SQL instance.

Here I got stuck and I'm wondering how I can establish the connection.
It would be great if someone would know how I can solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have your Cloud SQL instance a public IP?

Comment: I have a workaround where I added my laptop-ip to the whitelist and then I can connect to it with the public ip with <psql "sslmode=disable dbname=my-db user=my-user hostaddr=public-address>. I would prefer to use only a private-ip (if this is possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred solution is to use the public IP **BUT** without whitelisting any network. In fact, it's like if y ou have a public IP and all the connexion are forbidden.

The solution here is to use Cloud SQL proxy and to open a tunnel from your computer to the Cloud SQL database (that you reach on the public IP, but the tunnel is secured); It's exactly like a VPN connexion: a secure tunnel.

You can do this

- [Download Cloud SQL prowy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test#install-proxy)
- Launch it

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306
```

- Connect your SQL client on localhost:3306

*If the port 3306 is already in use, feel free to use another one*

---

If you prefer the private IP only (sometime, it's security team requirement), I wrote [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a).

If you use a VPN (and you are connected to Cloud VPN) take care to open the correct route and firewalls in both way (in and out)